# PayPal Payments Advanced - Hosted Checkout Pages on mobile

Tags: mobile, paypal

I'm using PayPal Payments Advanced with the hosted checkout pages for a mobile site and can't seem to get it to render as a mobile view on my phone.  I've followed their documentation but nothing seems to be working:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#hosted-pages-and-mobile-browsers

It clearly says:

> PayPal’s hosted checkout pages are mobile optimized for iPhone, iPod and Android devices. This mobile optimized experience is available for all 3 Layout templates A, B and C. In the case of Layouts A and B, PayPal will auto-detect if the checkout page is being viewed from a supported mobile browser and will redirect to the mobile optimized checkout page.

We are using Layout B, which should be mobile friendly according to the above, but it definitely does not look mobile friendly.  I've also tried adding `TEMPLATE=TEMPLATEB` to the `POST` data that hits this page but that doesn't work either.  Here is a screenshot of what it looks like on my LG G4:

[image: PayPal Hosted Checkout Mobile View]

As you can see, it doesn't look very mobile-friendly.  The thing is, when I click the "Checkout with PayPal" button it does go to a mobile-friendly version of the PayPal login, but I need *this* page to be mobile-friendly.  Does anyone have a clue as to how I can get this to work or is this a limitation with PayPal?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am struggling with this same issue

Comment: @BarryChapman yes, we had to add `TEMPLATE=MOBILE` to our post data on the call to get the secure token from PayPal.  And also, you actually can't use Template C; we had to use Template A (I think B may work as well, but C is basically useless).  The documentation on the PayPal tech site is horrible, and it actually directly contradicts this solution.

Comment: @jtate : I followed the steps you mentioned I.e., passed  &TEMPLATE=MOBILE while generating the SecureToken via "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com" and also added a hidden variable 
<input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateB" /> in form post to "https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com". Still the PayPal screen that came up was not mobile-friendly. 
Could you please advise if I am missing anything.  Find the screenshot (mobile)  https://ibb.co/hNTj2J

Comment: @shikhar I never actually confirmed that this worked with template B.  Could you check and see if template A works for you?  If so, then to use template B it may require you make other changes which I'm not sure about.

Comment: @jtate: I did try out templateA and retained other configurations which you had suggested, still it was the non responsive page that came up, please advise.?

Comment: @shikhar I'm honestly not sure.  I haven't worked on this solution in years and no longer have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal screen became responsive when we passed SecureToken and SecureTokenId as querystring parameters instead of passing those values as form post.

That is instead of passing in form post.

```
<html>
<body onload='document.forms["myForm1"].submit()'>
<form id='myForm1' method='POST' action='https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com'>
<input type="hidden" name="SECURETOKEN" value="..." />
<input type="hidden" name="SECURETOKENID" value="..." />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

We passed those values as querystring parameters.

```
https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKENID=...&SECURETOKEN=...
```

Not very sure why PayPal is handling those differently.